# Getting the type of a known property in generic object

Tags: typescript, types

How do i get type for known property of generic object.

For example:

```
export class someclass extends BehaviorSubject<T> {

  constructor(initialValue: T) {
      super(initialValue)
  }

  patch(value: Partial<T>) {
      this.next({ ...this.getValue(), ...value });
  }

  ...

  portion(key: keyof T){
    return {

      ...

      setValue :(value: ***THE TYPE OF THIS VALUE***) => this.patch({
        [key]: value as any
      } as Partial<T>)
    }
  }
}
```

In this example i have a class that extends BehaviorSubject.

I created a portion function that get some key that exists in the type T of the BehaviorSubject,
the portion is a function that get a key and return an object with couple of functions, one of these function is setValue.

This function get a value to patch into the BehaviorSubject in the key that we got in the portion function.

I'm trying to add the type for value so it will not be any but the right type as in T[key]

---

I know it's possible to add myself (like the example below) but i don't want to

```
  portion<K>(key: keyof T){
    return {

      ...

      setValue :(value: K) => this.patch({
        [key]: value as any
      } as Partial<T>)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to add generic type at the level of `portion` method. Consider below:

```
portion<K extends keyof T>(key: K){
    return {

      ...

      setValue: (value: T[K]) => this.patch({
        [key]: value
      } as Record<K, T[K]>)
    }
  }
```

Simplified version in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=15&ssc=20&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4GUIFtgDCqGAPACoB8cA3gFBxySwCWEAdiQNJygzBsATTAGtgATwgAzOJQAUosQC44nAJR0GDKMBgBXKGxr1NDNDoBqKJLuCLZANys3lZANqcAuqrgBeKrI0TTVcFD2VHa2BjEwBfOHQ4ACVgBGgBLgAaGXcPClVouBjjIqLaVLY0eBRfODZgAHdsPEJiNBJqEGVKqGY2AHMspVrdXAAjYCgYillVAG4y9kq4bTRdJHgfeIA6JhhWNlkAchBDudoFivgVtZgAJhrr9a2zGEtIo-YkMSwYHv6AQTQAA0AJJoH5-PqneaPO5bEBwAD0iLg3V6fSAA)

---

Final version by the code linked in the comment:

```
export class SLocal<T> extends BehaviorSubject<T> {

    constructor(initialValue: T) {
        super(initialValue)
    }

    patch(value: Partial<T>) {
        this.next({ ...this.getValue(), ...value });
    }

    setState(value: T) {
        this.next(value);
    }

    portion<K extends keyof T>(key: K){
      return {
        asObservable: () => this.pipe(pluck(key)),
        getValue :() => this.getValue()[key],
        setValue :(value: T[K]) => this.patch({
          [key]: value
        } as Record<K, T[K]> as Partial<T>)
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's giving me all of the possible type in T, for example if i have a property from string type and another property of number type it's giving me both number and string and not just the type of the key

Comment: Strange, I do not see that possible with such generic. Consider example in the playground, added a link to the answer. Also I think  as Partial<T> is a problem as it will say that all fields can be or not there, better would be as `Record<K,T[K]>`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-tq49e6 if you put your mouse on the setValue of portion you will see string | number

Comment: updated the stackblitz for future viewr https://stackblitz.com/edit/complex-component-state